# Responds from Http request is different from Python and browser

Tags: python, httprequest, httpresponse

I am testing the Python library request to see if it is suitable for my work. Here is my sample code for reference:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.genenetwork.org/webqtl/main.py?cmd=sch&gene=Grin2b&tissue=hip&format=text"

print url
print requests.get(url)
```

My Output:

http://www.genenetwork.org/webqtl/main.py?cmd=sch&gene=Grin2b&tissue=hip&format=text
Response [200]

Output that I get from my browser & my expected result:

[image]

What made the differences? How can I get my expected results? I wanted to process the data inside the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently printing the status code of your GET request. You can access the requested content via the `text` attribute of the [`Response`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) class returned by the `get` method.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.genenetwork.org/webqtl/main.py?cmd=sch&gene=Grin2b&tissue=hip&format=text")
r.text
```